# What is the bifurcation called in this very simple example?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, bifurcation

The most simple kind of bifurcation studied in texts is generally a fold, characteristic of equations such as:

$$\dot{y}=y^2+\lambda$$

There are two equilibria if $\lambda<0$, and no equilibria if $\lambda>0$. But what about a linear equation such as:

$$\dot{y}=\lambda y $$

In this case, there is a unstable equilibrium point if $\lambda>0$ and a stable equilibrium point if $\lambda<0$. While equilibria have not disappeared like in the fold above, it has "changed its sign". What's the name for this kind of bifurcation?

EDIT: The earlier equation did not show the stability behavior I wrote, this one should.

Comment: The term "bifurcation" in everyday English means to split or divide into branches. For that reason and also because the linear case is just not the critical/interesting case for ODEs/dynamical systems it may not have gotten enough attention to have a standard name. Interesting question though.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dot y=λy$$ is not in general position. As such this is not a named bifurcation. To test this, add some small "random" term
$$
\dot y=λy+ϵq(y), ~~~ q(y)=y(y+1),
$$
note that $q$ is smooth and keeps the equilibrium point $y=0$.
Then the perturbed right side has further roots at
$$
y=-1-\fracλϵ.
$$
You can change the type of the resulting bifurcation by changing the perturbation. So with $q(y)=-y^3$ you get the additional equilibria at
$$
y^2=\fracλϵ.
$$
This is however a special construction, the general type will remain the crossing like in the first example.